# Minimum number of iterations in matrix where cell value replaced by maximum of neighbour cell value in single iteration

Tags: python, algorithm, matrix

I have an matrix with values in each cell (minimum value=1), where the maximum value is 'max'.

At a time, I modify each cell value by the highest value of its neighboring cells i.e. all 8 neighbors, and this occurs for the whole matrix, simultaneously. I want to find after what minimum number of iterations after which value of all cells will be max.

One brute force method of doing this is by padding the matrix by zeros, and

```
for i in range (1,x_max+1):
    for j in range(1,y_max+1):
    maximum = 0 
        for k in range(-1,2):
            for l in range(-1,2):
                if matrix[i+k][j+l]>maximum:
                    maximum = matrix[i+k][j+l]
        matrix[i][j] = maximum
```

But is there an intelligent and faster way of doing this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `matrix[i][j] = maximum` will not work as subsequent `if matrix[i+k][j+l]>maximum` need access to the _original_ value.  Suggest using 2 matrices.

Comment: Oh yes...We will need 2 matrices in order to access original value. Thanks. Noted.
But still can it be implemented without using brute force method? Something more faster and clever.

Comment: Why `range(-1,2)`?  For 8 neighbors I would expect `range(-1,1) - inclusive`?  Or is this some sort of python-esse?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this can be solved by BFS(Breadth first Search).

Start BFS simulatneously with all the matrix cells with 'max' value.

```
  dis[][]  == infinite // min. distance of cell from nearest cell with 'max' value, initially infinite for all
  Q // Queue
  M[][] // matrix
  for all i,j   // travers the matrix, enqueue all cells with 'max'
    if M[i][j] == 'max' 
       dis[i][j] = 0 , Q.push( cell(i,j) )
  while !Q.empty:
       cell Current = Q.front 
       for all neighbours Cell(p,q) of Current: 
              if dis[p][q] == infinite
                 dis[p][q] = dis[Current.row][Current.column] + 1
                 Q.push( cell(p,q))
       Q.pop()
```

The cell with max(dis[i][j])  for all i,j will be the no. of iterations needed.

Answer (score 1):

Use an array with a "border".

Testing the edge conditions is tedious and can be avoided by making the array 1-bigger around the edge, each element with the value of `INT_MIN`.

Additionally, consider 8 tests, rather than a double nested loop

```
// Data is in matrix[1...N][1...M], yet is size matrix[N+2][M+2]
for (i=1; i <= N; i++) {
  for (j=1; j <= M; j++) {
    maximum = matrix[i-1][j-l];
    if (matrix[i-1][j+0] > maximum) maximum = matrix[i-1][j+0];
    if (matrix[i-1][j+1] > maximum) maximum = matrix[i-1][j+1];
    if (matrix[i+0][j-1] > maximum) maximum = matrix[i+0][j-1];
    if (matrix[i+0][j+0] > maximum) maximum = matrix[i+0][j+0];
    if (matrix[i+0][j+1] > maximum) maximum = matrix[i+0][j+1];
    if (matrix[i+1][j-1] > maximum) maximum = matrix[i+1][j-1];
    if (matrix[i+1][j+0] > maximum) maximum = matrix[i+1][j+0];
    if (matrix[i+1][j+1] > maximum) maximum = matrix[i+1][j+1];
    newmatrix[i][j] = maximum
```

Answer (score 1):

All existing answers require examining every cell in the matrix.  If you don't already know what the locations of the maximum value are, this is unavoidable, and in that case, [Amit Kumar's BFS algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44293166/47984) has optimal time complexity: O(wh), if the matrix has width w and height h.

OTOH, perhaps you already know the locations of the k maximum values, and k is relatively small.  In that case, the following algorithm will find the answer in just O(k^2*(log(k)+log(max(w, h)))) time, which is much faster when either w or h is large.  It doesn't actually look at *any* matrix entries; instead, it runs a binary search to look for candidate stopping times (that is, answers).  For each candidate stopping time it builds the set of rectangles that would be occupied by `max` by that time, and checks whether any matrix cell remains uncovered by a rectangle.

To explain the idea, we first need some terms.  Call the top row of a rectangle a "starting vertical event", and the row below its bottom edge an "ending vertical event".  A "basic interval" is the interval of rows spanned by any pair of vertical events that does not have a third vertical event anywhere between them (the event pairs defining these intervals can be from the same or different rectangles).  Notice that with k rectangles, there can never be more than 2k+1 basic intervals -- there is no dependence here on h.

The basic idea is to walk left-to-right through the columns of the matrix that correspond to *horizontal events*: columns in which either a new rectangle "starts" (the left vertical edge of a rectangle), or an existing rectangle "finishes" (the column to the right of the right vertical edge of a rectangle), keeping track of how many rectangles are currently covering every basic interval.  If we ever detect a basic interval covered by 0 rectangles, we can stop: we have found a column containing one or more cells that are not yet covered at time t.  If we get to the right edge of the matrix without this happening, then all cells are covered at time t.

Here is pseudocode for a function that checks whether any matrix cell remains uncovered by time `t`, given a length-k array `peak`, where `(peak[i].x, peak[i].y)` is the location of the i-th `max`-containing cell in the original matrix, in increasing order of x co-ordinate (so the leftmost `max`-containing cell is at `(peak[1].x, peak[1].y)`).

```
Function IsMatrixCovered(t, peak[]) {
    # Discover all vertical events and basic intervals
    Let vertEvents[] be an empty array of integers.
    For i from 1 to k:
        top = max(1, peak[i].y - t)
        bot = min(h, peak[i].y + t)
        Append top to vertEvents[]
        Append bot+1 to vertEvents[]

    Sort vertEvents in increasing order, and remove duplicates.

    x = 1
    Let horizEvents[] be an empty array of { col, type, top, bot } structures.

    For i from 1 to k:
        # Calculate the (clipped) rectangle that peak[i] will cover at time t:
        lft = max(1, peak[i].x - t)
        rgt = min(w, peak[i].x + t)
        top = max(1, peak[i].y - t)
        bot = min(h, peak[i].y + t)

        # Convert vertical positions to vertical event indices
        top = LookupIndexUsingBinarySearch(top, vertEvents[])
        bot = LookupIndexUsingBinarySearch(bot+1, vertEvents[])

        # Record horizontal events
        Append (lft, START, top, bot) to horizEvents[]
        Append (rgt+1, STOP, top, bot) to horizEvents[]

    Sort horizEvents in increasing order by its first 2 fields, with START considered < STOP.

    # Walk through all horizontal events, from left to right.
    Let basicIntervals[] be an array of size(vertEvents[]) integers, initially all 0.
    nOccupiedBasicIntervalsFirstCol = 0
    For i from 1 to size(horizEvents[]):
        If horizEvents[i].type = START:
            d = 1
        Else (if it is STOP):
            d = -1

        If horizEvents[i].col <= w:
            For j from horizEvents[i].top to horizEvents[i].bot:
                If horizEvents[i].col = 1 and basicIntervals[j] = 0:
                    ++nOccupiedBasicIntervalsFirstCol      # Must be START
                basicIntervals[j] += d
                If basicIntervals[j] = 0:
                    return FALSE

    If nOccupiedBasicIntervalsFirstCol < size(basicIntervals):
        return FALSE         # Could have checked earlier, but the code is simpler this way

    return TRUE
}
```

The above function can simply be called inside a binary search on t, that looks for the smallest value of t for which the function returns TRUE.

A further factor of k/log(k) could be removed by exploiting the fact that the set of basic intervals affected by any rectangle starting or ending is always an interval, through the use of [Fenwick trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenwick_tree).